# ThreeJS Gltf has been loaded but model is not visible (Production build)

Tags: reactjs, three.js, create-react-app

I have a reactjs based application that renders 3D models. I'm using `react-three-fiber` library for this application and as well as ThreeJs as it's peer dependency. For my 3D file, I'm using `.gltf` format, I also tried `.glb`. For the loader I'm using `GLTFLoader` from ThreeJs library. Everything is actually working great on my local machine. But when I tried a production build `NODE_ENV=production` that's where the problem is. The `.gltf` was loaded but nothing is showing on the screen. Does anyone experienced this kind of issue with threejs built for production?

Comment: Can you please share the glTF asset in this thread?

Comment: @Mugen87 thank you for the response. Do you think the glTF asset is the issue? Please note that it is working locally on my machine.

Comment: I was hoping you could setup a live example with the asset so it's possible o debug the issue. Something like https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/

Comment: Here is a quick sample https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-leavitt-n7sd3?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Thanks for sharing the live example! However, the t-shirt model is rendered fine on my system.

Comment: Yes- it does render fine. Try downloading and build it for production `yarn build`. Then `serve` or `http-server` on the `build` directory. You should see what I'm talking about.

Comment: Okay, I can actually reproduce on my system. Sorry, but I'm not familiar with react so I can not help with this issue. I can see that the initial box is visible but is visible but for some reasons as soon as the glTF is loaded the screen becomes white.

Comment: Right- that's exactly what's happening. No worries man, but thanks for checking...

Comment: could you drop it into a codesandbox? it reminds me of this https://github.com/react-spring/react-three-fiber/discussions/584 the problem is similar, worked in dev, but not in prod. the issue was with how he treats the model data, he made react dispose it.

Comment: Hi @hpalu, that is exactly the solution. I posted it here but the mods removed it. That is the same post/issue that I posted on github.